# what is mean "type" in alertify.log(Notification,type, wait); in alertify.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using alertify.js verson 0.3.11 in http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/

on there one function is like that-

alertify.log("Notification", type, wait);

i can't understand 3rd parameter(type)

Comment: It's a simple variable with the identifier `type`, declared as a parameter [right here](https://github.com/fabien-d/alertify.js/blob/0.3.11/src/alertify.js#L383). What's the problem?

Comment: sorry, its 2nd parameter

Answer (score 2):

The `type` parameter makes slight changes to how the dialog looks, in terms of its background colour.

You can just leave it blank (pass a blank string `""` as the `type` argument) or use either `"success"` or `"error"`. If you use `"success"`, the dialog has a green background, while `"error"` causes it to have a red background.

### Examples

Using `alertify.log("Foo", "success", 0)`:

[image]

Using `alertify.log("Foo", "error", 0)`:

[image]

Using `alertify.log("Foo", "", 0)`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @Bergi said, it's a variable with an identifier type. It can take a String such as `success` or `error` and then gets injected into a css class like `.ajs-{type}`